# sort on part of the line, keep order on tie

Tags: git, bash, sorting, git-log

I would like to order some output of git log by date (not by time)

Unfortunately it seems to be impossible to sort only by some characters, ignoring the rest of the line with `sort`. What I tried so far:

Input: git-log.txt

```
git log --date-order --reverse --show-all --pretty="%ai#%h %s"

2013-08-22 09:54:12 +0200#f03fec1 G  
2013-08-21 10:43:57 +0200#c026cd6 A
2013-08-21 10:49:58 +0200#4630c3f B
2013-08-21 11:14:42 +0200#6e7141d C
2013-08-21 13:02:59 +0200#23ab0a8 D
2013-08-21 10:39:23 +0200#06b83f7 E
2013-08-21 14:10:16 +0200#f53384e F
2013-08-20 16:22:33 +0200#12591fb Z
```

naiv: This will sort perfectly including date

```
sort -k 1.1,1.10 git-log.txt
```

tricking by solving ties with not existing column

```
sort -k 1.1,1.10 -k 200 git-log.txt
```

tricking it to interpret whole line as single column with not existing separation character

```
sort -k 1.1,1.10 -t "^" git-log.txt
```

in all cases, output is:

```
2013-08-20 16:22:33 +0200#12591fb Z
2013-08-21 10:39:23 +0200#06b83f7 E
2013-08-21 10:43:57 +0200#c026cd6 A
2013-08-21 10:49:58 +0200#4630c3f B
2013-08-21 11:14:42 +0200#6e7141d C
2013-08-21 13:02:59 +0200#23ab0a8 D
2013-08-21 14:10:16 +0200#f53384e F
2013-08-22 09:54:12 +0200#f03fec1 G
```

I need (see the position of commit E)

```
2013-08-20 16:22:33 +0200#12591fb Z
2013-08-21 10:43:57 +0200#c026cd6 A
2013-08-21 10:49:58 +0200#4630c3f B
2013-08-21 11:14:42 +0200#6e7141d C
2013-08-21 13:02:59 +0200#23ab0a8 D
2013-08-21 10:39:23 +0200#06b83f7 E
2013-08-21 14:10:16 +0200#f53384e F
2013-08-22 09:54:12 +0200#f03fec1 G
```

How to teach `sort` to keep sort order on a tie?
I can add any needed character the output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `-s` option for `sort`:

```
   -s, --stable
          stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison
```

Say

```
sort -k 1.1,1.10 -t "^" -s git-log.txt
```

instead.

Comment: I'm feeling dumb now. Have read man pages for 2 hours, overlooking it. :-( Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note also the sort --debug option to help with this (it would have made the second problematic sort obvious in this case)